# Schema for a UTF-8 blog post

Tags: mysql, text, utf-8, innodb, varchar

I'm trying to design a GENERIC blog/journal CMS ( consider the word GENERIC fairly important for my needs ). The whole database will be handled with MySQL.

Considering:

- the max row length of MySQL ( 65535 B )
- the storage needed for a string in UTF-8 ( up to 3 times the number of characters )

It does make sense use a VARCHAR(20000) that should be at max 60000 B to store the posts content to enhance performances instead of using TEXT?

It's a limitation, but I thought to avoid the problem, storing an id_parent_post, to concatenate related posts as "chapters" if necessary.

---

Another question is relatively the table engine.

InnoDB full-text search is available only in MySQL 5.6. Nowadays, using MyISAM tables, for this purpose only, still has sense?

Probably a Lucene-based solution is the best way to solve problem, but if it's not possible ( hosting policy for example ), what engine I should choose?

Comment: InnoDB because, it supports foreign keys. You will index your dbase, wouldn't you? If you think your blog can exceed "text" limit. then, Google for "Big Table"

Comment: Is your primary concern *performance*? Is this really a concern for a regular CMS? How many entries do you expect and what sort of complicated operations are you going to do on it that performance or even storage space is your primary concern? Do you have numbers to prove that a `LONGTEXT` column is not sufficient?

Comment: @KarmicDice could you post some reference to use BigTable?

Comment: @deceze it's not a priority, but if 20000 chars fits a generic need, why not?
A LONGTEXT it's stored in a different file?

Comment: http://hbase.apache.org/ Hbase is too much for a blog website. try MongoDB .

Comment: No, a LONGTEXT is simply a TEXT column with a higher byte limit. It's pretty hard to produce enough content in a regular CMS to exceed its limit.